# How to reset excel column if max reach

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, office365

I have excel document with an field which has numbers, what I like to do is get that number from an field and add 3 to it but if the adding 3 takes it over 10 then I want excel to reset to 1 and count the remaining numbers

A1=9

When I do this =A1+3=2 (when it counts the number it goes 9, 10 then it reset to 1 and 2)

I try following but Can't get it right

- =If((A1+3)>10, A1-3)
- =MID(A1+3,10)
- =IF((A15+$I$2)>$I$4,A15-$I$2,A15+$I$2) This does work but only way is to go back not forward

I'm not sure how I can do this

Comment: Try to give a sample table, I cannot understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOD is the function designed to do this in Excel - it takes the "modulus" of a number which is the remainder after dividing by another number. use it like this:

```
=MOD(A1+3,10)
```

Notice however that this means 10 will give a result of 0 because 10 divides evenly by 10 with no remainder. You often need to modify the terms of your MOD function to adjust for the edge cases. In your case, I think you need:

```
=1+MOD(A1+3-1,10)
```

(obviously +3-1 is the same as +2, but it may help anyone troubleshooting this to see your intent more clearly, and not try to "fix" your +2 to a +3),